# Iterating Over an Array and Returning First Match from MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of `Users` in my database with corresponding unique `ids`. I am writing a function that takes an array of ids as an argument, e.g:
`["user_id1", "user_id2", "user_id3", "user_id4"]`.

I want my query to return the first and only the first match. i.e. Using the example above, if `user_id2` and `user_id4` were the only two matching users in the database, my result would only return `user_id2`. User ids that are not in the database are ignored.

My current approach is to use a while loop, but I wanted to see if there was a better solution provided by Mongoose.

Current Pseudo Code:

```
function findOneUser(userIdArr) {
    let user = 0;
    let returnedUser;
    while(!returnedUser || user < userIdArr.length) {
        let id = userIdArr[user];
        user = await User.findByID(id);
        user++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the [MongoDB $in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#examples) query with `limit()` applied on the resulting cursor to get the first match.

Comment: @prasad_ I set this up using `const foundUser = await User.find({ "_id": { $in : userIds }}).limit(1);` However, this is returning the last matching user instead of the first? I would want to stop querying if a match is found.

I also tried `const foundUser = await User.find().where('_id').in(userIds).limit(1);`

Comment: mongoose [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne) does just that. `findOne({_id: {$in:[...]}})`

Comment: @ISAE tested your edited query as well, and same thing, returning the last index item...
`async function pullFirstUser(userIds) {
 const foundUser = await User.findOne({_id: { $in: userIds }})
 return foundUser;
}
let userIdArr = ["60d9e2e0d092bd33d0ebab4b","60d9e2e0d092bd33d0ebab47", "60d9e2e0d092bd33d0ebab3b"]
pullFirstUser(userIdArr);`


`result -> 60d9e2e0d092bd33d0ebab3b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

Use promises and mongoose findOne method:

```
 let argumentArr = ["user_id1", "user_id2", "user_id3", "user_id4"];
 let getUser = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   for (let i = 0; i < argumentArr.length; i++) {
     User.findOne({_id:argumentArr[i]}).then(user => {
       if(Object.keys(user).length > 0){
         resolve(user)
       }
     }).catch(err => {reject(err)})
   }
 });

 getUser.then(
  (user) => {console.log(user);},//expected results: user(:object)
  (err) => {console.log(err);}
 );
}
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in this code I believe

Comment: Thank you. i had to try to simplify it. i hope this helps.